# Getting "Unrecognized SameSiteMode value -1" InvalidOperationException in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, samesite

I'm running some tests to prepare for the upcoming Chrome version with the changes to SameSite handling of cookies, but my web application is giving trouble. I can reproduce it in the following way:

1. Use Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.3) to create a new project.
2. Pick "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and enable https.
3. Add a "Scaffolded Item" and add ASP.NET Core Identity.
4. When asked, scaffold all files, and add a fresh data context and user, using SQLite:

   [image: step 4 in a dialog]
5. Add `services.AddRazorPages();` to Startup
6. Add `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` into the `UseEndpoints` configuration lambda
7. Add the `SameSiteCookiesServiceCollectionExtensions` as [suggested by ThinkTecture](https://www.thinktecture.com/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/) and use it by adding `services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();` to your Startup. Alternatively, just leave out the browser sniffing part (not needed for this repro I think), skip copying linked solution, and instead do this:

   ```
   services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode)(-1);
   });
   ```
8. Add `app.UseCookiePolicy();` to Startup to enable the code
9. Start the application (for me it starts in IIS Express on `https://localhost:44342/`)
10. Navigate to `https://localhost:44342/Identity/Account/Login`

The result for me is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   **InvalidOperationException: Unrecognized SameSiteMode value -1**
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.ResponseCookiesWrapper.ApplyPolicy(string key, CookieOptions options)

The full stack trace, should it be important:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unrecognized SameSiteMode value -1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.ResponseCookiesWrapper.ApplyPolicy(string key, CookieOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.ResponseCookiesWrapper.ApplyAppendPolicy(ref string key, ref string value, CookieOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.ResponseCookiesWrapper.Append(string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager.DeleteCookie(HttpContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignOutAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
AuthTest.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnGetAsync(string returnUrl) in Login.cshtml.cs
+
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

If I check `dotnet --info` I see:

- `Host Version: 3.1.1`
- .NET Core SDKs installed: a whole bunch, up to and including `3.1.100` and `3.1.101`
- Several `.NET Core runtimes installed` including `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` versions `3.1.0` and `3.1.1`

Some additional details and attempted workarounds:

- csproj contains `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` that should (as far as I know) use the latest stuff available
- I've rebooted to make sure there is no transient problem lingering
- one colleague with a Windows machine, can reproduce the problem
- another colleague, with a Linux Mint machine, does *not* have the problem
- I've tried `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` but it didn't help
- I can see the error line [in the 3.0.0 sources](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/aee5e4080331553ea9dfb7fb388b6d72f715bf6a/src/Security/CookiePolicy/src/ResponseCookiesWrapper.cs#L263) but not [in the 3.1.0 sources](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2b7e994b8a304700a09617ffc5052f0d943bbcba/src/Security/CookiePolicy/src/ResponseCookiesWrapper.cs#L246-L250) (or master) of ASP NET Core
- I have tried `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.1.101` to force the right version, but it didn't work (though I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about using one)
- I want to try to remove specific versions from my machine but I [run into problems uninstalling things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59839937/419956) (apart from the fact that the Version Selection features should render that approach unnecessary, right?)

So I *presume* I'm facing a variant of [this ASP.NET Core GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18362) that mentions my version is too low? But I'm not sure how to proceed now, since I feel I already cleared everything.

What am I missing here? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: having a `global.json` which may override the sdk version? Also do you get the error locally or after deploying? Because of forward rolling, the latest runtime needs to be installed on the target system too. Or you deploy as self-contained application (which includes the side-by-side runtime

Comment: @Tseng This is on localhost, a fully updated Windows 10 1909 machine, that does seem to have the latest .NET Core SDKs, and I presumed that creating a fresh project with a fully updated Visual Studio would also use latest NuGet packages. I'm not aware of having a `global.json` but will check. - I do see the generated project file uses `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` which has no explicit version number, so that might be the culprit...

Comment: Well the implicit version is the recommended approach since 2.1. It will look for the installed version for your target (`netcore2.1`/ `netcore2.2` / `netcore3.0`/`netcore3.1`) and pick the latest installed runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1 / (Older version of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I think there are some bugs in Visual Studio 2019 `16.4.3`. Just after update to `16.4.3` all of my web applications that used  `Cookie` faced problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this happens if you do not pay attention and pick *3.0.x* in the Visual Studio dialogs for creating the application. If you pick the right one (3.1.x) you will get:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in your `.csproj` file, as well as `3.1.x` versions of several packages instead.

Not sure why Linux would specifically not have the issue, maybe it's just that those machines coincidentally don't have 3.0.x versions of dotnet core available or installed, and it runs your code against 3.1, thus obscuring the problem?

Comment: I speculate that the other (Linux) machine cannot find the 3.0 runtime when it's needed, runs the 3.0 app with the 3.1 runtime, and thus "hides" the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities have been tried to try.
But the solution is this:
**You have to install this. ASP.NET Core Runtime 2.1.17**