# How to remove a dotnet runtime on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've found the command `dotnet --list-runtimes` and it outputs (abbreviated) for me:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I want to *remove* specific AspNetCore.App runtimes to see if it helps me solve [another, different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59836767/419956) - but I don't know how.

I've tried:

- Using Add/Remove Programs, but it only lists ".NET Core SDK" entries, not *runtimes* (also: this list is *missing* several versions that were in the `dotnet --list-runtimes` output)
- Going through the available `dotnet help` entries, but saw no relevant option
- Go through [the `remove-runtime-sdk-version` readme](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions.md) but it tells me to use Add/Remove Programs, which doesn't help me

I've *considered* removing the folders mentioned in my output, but am hesitant to just start deleting folders in `Program Files` subfolders.

Is there a `dotnet` command or other good way to remove runtimes, specifically AspNetCore versions, so that I can be 100% sure that the "Version Selection" feature from ASP.NET Core cannot pick up a wrong version?

---

Per the comments, I've tried the `dotnet-core-uninstall` tool (preview release), but if I run `dotnet-core-uninstall` it lists zero runtimes it could uninstall, only SDKs (and only 2.x versions at that).

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but it might help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. I've tried it, but it only lists ".NET Core SDKs" (and only 2.x versions) as things it can uninstall. No runtimes can be uninstalled with this tool according to `dotnet-core-uninstall list`

Comment: Not a (direct) answer to the question, but consider building and testing your app in a Docker container that only has the version(s) you want to test with. This avoids the need for changing and/or potentially breaking your development environment, and makes deployment a lot more predictable to boot (since production servers can never be expected to have all the stuff installed that you have installed).

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue as you experienced. Were you able to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hi! I'm facing similar issue. Server has .net runtime 3.1.32 and 3.1.31 installed. 3.1.31 doesn't show up in control panel and with the dotnet-core-uninstall list command but exists inside program files (x86). Have you found the solution on how to uninstall it?

Comment: Can't quite remember, it's been two years. I do see I upvoted the only answer but am not sure how well it worked at the time. Alas.

Comment: <thats_tha_neat_part.gif> :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There now is [a officially recommended method to uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool) .net runtime and sdk. The gist of it is:

- Install the ".NET Uninstall Tool"
- Use `dotnet-core-uninstall` with its various commands (`list`, `dry-run`, and `remove`)

Use with care!

Comment: I see a lot more items with `dotnet --list-runtimes` than with `dotnet-core-uninstall list`, including ones from other major versions. The second command only lists 3.1 and 6.0 versions, the first lists 2.1 and 5.0 versions as well.

Comment: Hi @etoyz  ! I'm facing similar issue. Server has .net runtime 3.1.32 and 3.1.31 installed. 3.1.31 doesn't show up in control panel and with the dotnet-core-uninstall list command but exists inside program files (x86). Have you found the solution on how to uninstall it?

Comment: @R.Schreurs the reason for this is what the tool states:
"This tool cannot uninstall versions of the runtime or SDK that are 
    - SDKs installed using Visual Studio 2019 Update 3 or later.
    - SDKs and runtimes installed via zip/scripts.
    - Runtimes installed with SDKs (these should be removed by removing that SDK)"
So, IMHO is a useful tool but not that handy as one may think.

Answer (score 3):

Try uninstalling Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime - 3.1.32 from Apps and Features.
The 3.1.32 .net Core libraries appeared to be bundled with them.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution is through the Visual Studio Installer:

1. Run the Visual Studio Installer
2. Click **Modify** next to your version of Visual Studio
3. Select the **Individual components** tab along the top
4. Under the **.NET** section, uncheck the runtime(s) to be removed
5. Click **Modify** in the bottom right corner of the dialog to apply the changes